# Starting point for bullet including player rotation in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, topdown

I'm making a simple topdown shooter game. The problem is with bullet starting point. I have player image where rifle barrel is between topmid and topright of rectangle. How to make bullet start always from the rifle barrel regardless image rotation?

```
# key input
def get_input(self, dt):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.direction.rotate_ip(dt * -360)

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.direction.rotate_ip(dt * 360)

    self.angle = self.direction.angle_to((0, -1))
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.movement = 1
        self.status = 'move'
    else:
        self.movement = 0
        self.status = 'idle'

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.movement = -1
        self.status = 'move'

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and not self.bullet.sprites():
        self.create_bullet(dt)
        shoot = pygame.mixer.Sound('audio/rumble.flac')
        shoot.play()

# movement
def move(self, speed, dt):
    movement_v = self.direction * self.movement
    if movement_v.length() > 0:
        movement_v.normalize_ip()
        self.pos += movement_v * dt * speed
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)

    #   boundary
    if self.rect.x <= 0:
        self.rect.x = 0
    if self.rect.x >= 1216:
        self.rect.x = 1216
    if self.rect.y <= 0:
        self.rect.y = 0
    if self.rect.y >= 704:
        self.rect.y = 704


# create bullet instance
def create_bullet(self, dt):
    self.bullet.add(Bullet(self.rect.center, self.direction.normalize(), self.bullet_speed, self.angle))
```

Comment: `self.rect.center` is the center of `self.image` but not *"between topmid and topright"*

Comment: i know i can put tuple (self.rect.centerx + 15, self.rect.centery) but it doesn't work to rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have rotate the offset of the bullet starting point with [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate). e.g.:

```py
offset = pygame.math.Vecotr2(15, 10) # (15, 10) is just an example
rotated_offset = offset.rotate(-self.angle) 
pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center) + rotated_offset 
bullet = Bullet((pos.x, pos.y), ...)
```